# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el método findByIdAndRemove y deleteOne?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

les agradezco si me podrían decir la diferencia entre estos dos métodos para eliminar de mongoose, ¿cuál debemos de usar para eliminar un único elemento si parece que hacen lo mismo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [`findByIdAndRemove()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37553/4326551)

Remueve un documento pasando como parámetro su id. Internamente hace un match con el campo `_id` del modelo. Es equivalente a hacer `findOneAndRemove({ _id: id }, ...)` **y dispara el middleware** `findOneAndRemove`.

Hay que notar que este devuelve el documento eliminado en caso de que se quiera dar opción a restaurar la información.

## [`deleteOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteOne)

Elimina el primer documento que cumpla las condiciones que se le pasen. A diferencia de `findByIdAndRemove()` aquí se puede agregar una condición diferente del `_id` Hay que notar que **no dispara ningun hook como** `pre('remove')` **y** `post('remove')` y no devuelve el documento eliminado.

El uso depende de lo que quieras lograr. Generalmente el primero permite mayor certeza al eliminar por id y su uso es más común, pero en el caso de constantes operaciones de eliminación donde los documentos cambian de manera rápida y no siempre se usa el `_id` auto-generado, `deleteOne` da mayor flexibilidad.